# PHP javac check

Tags: php, javac

I hope someone can help me I have the following running in a PHP file

`var_dump(exec('command -v javac'))`

I have also tried

`exec('command -v javac', $output);`
`echo $output;`

All however return `""` running the same `command -v javac` on the CLI in linux gives me what i'm looking for.

Can anyone think of a reason why this would be happening?

For example I have also used  `exec('whoami', $output);` which is returning the apache process owner so exec is working correctly.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Sorry i'm actually using `var_dump` as i'm debugging the longer `exec('command -v javac > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo 1 || echo 0');`

Which was coming back with 0

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
exec('command -v javac', $output);
```

$output will store the output of exec.

exec may be disabled on the host for security reasons and that is the other reason why it is returning empty string.

Comment: Tried and still coming back empty.

Comment: Are you sure exec and shell_exec are enabled on your host? Sometimes they are disabled for security reasons.

Comment: I have also run `exec('whoami', $output);` which gave me the hostname of the server so yeah it appears it's enabled.

Comment: You can try var_dump(exec('echo TEST')) and see the result. If it is still empty string then it is disabled.

Comment: So then if `command -v javac` is executable by the www-data user (or the user that runs php)? You can ls -ls the command and see the permissions

Comment: Apache is running on the same user as the user I have tested command -v javac

Comment: What if you try with `exec('command -v javac 2>&1', $output, $return);`

Comment: That one comes back with `array(0) { } int(1)`

Comment: This is for the $output? What about the $return ?

Comment: the `int(1)` is for `$return`

Comment: Do you know what `code 1` means from the output of this command ?